# Create user with Custom Attributes in Azure AD B2C with Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create user with Graph API. user json object is as shown below.  I have created a custom attribute called `Role`. So while creating the user i need to give some value this `Role` as well.  But if i include this custom attribute i am getting error.

> One or More properties are invalid

Create User is successful if i don't specify this custom attribute.

```
 var jsonObject = new JObject
            {
                {"accountEnabled", true},
                {"country", "India"},
                {"creationType", "LocalAccount"},
                {"givenName","given"},
                {"surName","surname"},
                {"extension_Role","Admin"},
                {"displayName","test12@xxx.com"},
                {"passwordPolicies", "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword"},
                {"passwordProfile", new JObject
                {
                    {"password", "Password@12"},
                    {"forceChangePasswordNextLogin", false}
                } },
                {"signInNames", new JArray
                    {
                        new JObject
                        {
                            {"value", "test12@xxx.com"},
                            {"type", "emailAddress"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

`extension_Role` is the property which is throwing error.  I tried giving `extension_appId_Role`. It gives a different error saying

> No extension properties exists with this name

I guess we cannot add custom attributes while creating the user. Only we can update them using edit profile. Correct me if i am wrong. I have added this custom attribute to `sign-up` and `edit-profile` policies and as claims.

**NOTE :** I gave proper permissions to graph API and registered an app with App Registration portal.

**Answer:**  I found the answer . But not sure if that is the correct behaviour.  I could insert custom attributes when i append it with `b2c-extensions-app` app id. I registered a separate app under `App Registrations` but not sure why it's still taking `default b2c-extensions-app` application id. May be it's because  i created custom user attributes before registering app in `App Registrations`.

Comment: I just created a user with a custom attribute `extension_[guid]_my_attribute`.

Comment: Have you read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#use-custom-attributes)?

Comment: Are you using custom policies or built-in policies?

Comment: I am using custom policies.

Comment: You must include the app ID of the "b2c-extensions-app" app in the attribute name because, when you create the user attribute in the Azure AD B2C portal, it is this extensions app that registers the custom attribute with the Azure AD directory.

Comment: So it is valid in the case of multiple applications having different users with same custom attribute name  e.g Role .   So always we need to use `b2c-extensions-app` app id.

Comment: Correct, @Venky, the "b2c-extensions-app" app owns the user attribute.

Answer (score 13):

As pointed out in a comment you need to specify the prefix `extension_` and the `b2c-extensions-app` app ID in the property name. The app ID is a GUID but must be included without the hyphens e.g.

```
extension_93ae98b337124e0aaced3698b59f8acb_Role
```

The `b2c-extension-app` ID can be found by selecting `All Resources -> App Registrations` in the Azure portal inside the Azure AD B2C tenant. By default it shows the list of `My apps`; change the dropdown to `All apps` then click the `b2c-extension-app` and copy its `Application ID`.

Comment: Thanks for the last bit of information there. I thought `b2c-extension-app` was an example app name and was using one of my app registration id's. This information helped me a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the B2C application from: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet and update the app.config with values for your b2c tenant. (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet for more info on setting up and using B2C).
2. Run B2C Get-B2C-Application: Copy the value of "objectId" (towards the top of the output).
3. Run B2C Get-Extension-Attribute objectid (where objectid is what you captured in step (2)). The output of which will have a name property for each custom property (eg: "name": "extension_appguid_customattributename")
4. The name from (3) is what you can use with the command B2C create-user "path_to_email.json". In the json, you add your property like so: "extension_appguid_customattributename":"this is a custom property!"

Note: one can find out the name of the custom attribute by finding the appid for the App registered in the B2C tenant under AAD (it has the name: b2c-extensions-app). You then append extension_appid_ to your custom attribute and then you can use it.

Comment: With:

B2C Get-Extension-Attribute <objectId>

you can even get a list of all your extension attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using built-in policies, you can't control the app it uses to store [custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr).

If you're using [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom), [see this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom#modifying-your-custom-policy-to-add-the-applicationobjectid) for configuring the app it uses to store custom attributes.

```xml
<ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
          <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.AzureActiveDirectoryProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <!-- Provide objectId and appId before using extension properties. -->
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">insert objectId here</Item>
            <Item Key="ClientId">insert appId here</Item>
          </Metadata>
        <!-- End of changes -->
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </ClaimsProvider>
</ClaimsProviders>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable those attributes (show them) for one of the signup policies (custom or not), and create an account through that policy that has a value set for them. They will not be available in that tenant and directory until you've done that.